# MySQL can't find insert?

Tags: php, mysql

I try to get the id of a page with `home = true`. Like this,

```
SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE home='true'
```

But it doesn't return anything. But when I do:

```
SELECT * FROM  `pages` WHERE id =  '1'
```

It works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this a wordpress database? What datatype is 'Home` ?

Comment: What is `home` for a data type? What do you see for content in `home` for the result in your second query?

Comment: add the schema of your table, the create statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> FIXED!

Changed the true/false to 1/0, now it works! Don't know why, but I don't really care just that it works.

Comment: Kevin Brechbühl and Shiva  asked data type... but you did not answer, why?  probably the data type int or tinyint... if so you can not insert true/false into this type of column... please next time read and answer reply related your question...

Comment: You know what? I _did_ answer longer down. And I changed it myself too see if it worked. Actually nobody helped me here.

Comment: nobody can help you if you answer on time or if you do not know how to ask a question... you answer after 30 minutes they ask... in mysql boolean type is just synonym to tinyint. you can not insert true or false value into...

Comment: You really have a problem? Then I'm sorry.

Comment: you did not need any answer here... you only struggle with others... you said  "Don't know why," and I said,id you why in previus answer. but instead to read and understand why, you prefer to attact to me (who  wants to help you)... GOOD LUCK TO YOU

Comment: Thank You. What do you mean by, I did not need an answer here?

Answer (score 2):

With `home='true'` you are doing a string comparison, while you want it to be boolean.

Hence, use

```
SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE home= true
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE home='true'
                                 ^    ^
```

Comment: What if you use capital letters? TRUE

Answer (score 2):

If the field is a boolean value, you should use `home = true`. Your single quotes specify that you're searching for a string type, when most likely a boolean is present.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use 'true' try just using true. That should work.